# Unitary operators - convergence problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, semigroup-of-operators

Let $\mathcal{U}:=\left\{ U(t) \colon t \geq 0\right\}$ be a family of unitary operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ where $U(0)=I$.

Assume that $\left| \left<\left( \frac{U(t)-I}{t} - A \right)v, w \right> \right|\stackrel{t \to 0}{\rightarrow} 0$ for all $v, w \in \mathcal{H}$, where $A$ is some bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$.
Can we somehow conclude that
$$ \left\| \left(\frac{U(t)-I}{t}-A\right)w \right\| \to 0 \ \ \forall_{w \in \mathcal{H}}, \ \mbox{ as } t \to 0?$$

If not, can we assume something more about $\mathcal{U}$ or $A$ to get this strong operator convergence?

Thank you for any hints, answers or good references.

Comment: I am not sure that it is useful here, but just in case: $x_n$ converges to $x$ in $H$ if and only if $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ and $\|x_n\|$ converges to $\|x\|$. So you see what extra assumption to add on your family for wot convergence to imply sot convergence. But maybe this can be removed or weakened.

Comment: Is $U(t)$ a $C_0$ semigroup, by the way?

Comment: It is not a $C_0$ semigroup. I know that if $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $x$ and $\|x_n\|$ converges to $\|x\|$ then $(x_n)$ converges strongly to $x$. This is due polarization identity, but I don't won't to add this extra assumption.

Comment: That's even easier than polarization: $\|x-x_n\|^2=(x-x_n,x-x_n)=\|x\|^2+\|x_n\|^2-(x,x_n)-(x_n,x)$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. My answer to your 2nd comment: for a strongly continuous one parameter unitary group we have Stone's theorem, for $C_0$ we have Hille-Yoshide. Then $A$ will be an infinitesimal generator of a given semi-group, but here no such assumption is made.